Understanding on how to use Markov/Chebyshev inequalities
I'm going through some qualifying exams for master's studies and I've met some strange task. This exam asumes one knows Markov, Chebyshev and Chernoff inequalities.
A sufficient condition for the inequality $$ P (|X| ≥ 10) > \frac{1}{10} $$ to hold is that the random
variable X:

has variance equal to 50
is nonnegative and its expected value is equal to 20
has expected value equal to 1000

With my current knowledge, I could only say with confidence that statement 1. is false, as it doesn't provide any information about the expected value.
For 2. and 3., using Markov inequality I would know that P(X >= 10) <= 1, which doesn't help too much. Also I can imagine that for 2. you could get many 0s and 1 high value, bringing EX to 10. Same for 3., so I would call all statements False.
However my question is if there is something to be done when the direction of inequality is negated P(X >= t) < Y, or when we estimate P(X < t) >= Y. For the latter, would it be true that P(X < t) = 1 - P(X >= t)?
Also, like in 3., if I don't know whether X has nonnegative values (which is required to use Markov inequality), but we have question about P(|X| >= t), would it be equivalent to estimating this for Y=|X|, since Y has nonnegative values?

Best to construct actual counterexamples.  For instance, for $#1$, cnsider $X$ which is $\pm N$ with equal probabilities $p=\frac 1{20}$ and then $\pm (10-\epsilon)$ with equal probabilities.  What's the variance of that (as a function of $N,p$)?
